# error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol when calling IMSL from IVF?

Tags: fortran, static-libraries, intel-fortran, imsl

I got a branch of errors when I compile and link my source code with IVF+IMSL. It looks like

```
>main.f90
    1>Linking...
    1>msvcrt.lib(MSVCR120.dll) : error LNK2005: __time32 has already defined in LIBCMT.lib(time.obj) 
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1ucs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1inpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(flexlm.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1lock.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e2psh_lmf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1prt.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(n1rgb.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1mes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1std.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1sti.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1stl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(dr1ins.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1psh_lmf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(n1rty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1pop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(dr1t64.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(r1in32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(dr1t32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(r1inf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(rnset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(drnun.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(r1int.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsl.lib(r1in64.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_global_thread_num
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1inpl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1init.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1prt.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(n1rgb.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1ucs.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1mes.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1std.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1sti.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1stl.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(dr1ins.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1psh_lmf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(n1rty.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsls_err.lib(e1pop.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(dr1t64.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(r1in32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(dr1t32.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(r1inf.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(rnset.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(drnun.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(r1int.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
    1>imsl.lib(r1in64.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol ___kmpc_threadprivate_cached
```

I guess one possible source of the error is that my source code is from other author and was written a couple years ago (around 2004). So my IMSL version (7.0) may be different from his. In the original code, it called IMSL using command like `INCLUDE 'link_f90_static.h'`,but it failed with `Error #5102: cannot open link_f90_static.h`. Alternatively, I substituted this command with

```
  include link_fnl_static.h
```

and the Error #5102 was resolved. But a branch of LNK2019 errors emerge. I don't know if it's really caused by the IMSL version problem.
A similar thread in the intel fortran user forum is https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/298641
but since I have never installed CVF，it may not be source of my problem

Any suggestion? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the Intel-supplied IMSL instructions say, if you are going to link to the static library form of IMSL you also need to link to the OpenMP libraries. One way to do that is to add the line:

!DEC$ OBJCOMMENT LIB:"libiomp5md.lib"

following that INCLUDE line.

But my preferred choice would be for you to include 'link_fnl_shared.h' instead. This would probably also take care of that __time32 reference.